# Categorizing labels using same categorization as labeled layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, symbology, rule-based

I am using QGIS 3.28.

Use-case: I have a layer named: map_1, which is a map of many regions. The regions are identified with City_id. To distinguish the regions by their ID's, I first categorized them by random colors, and second added a label based on the field "City_id". See attached screenshots.

[image: A sample of the map, showing the categorized regions of the layer, with their labels]

Problem: Since some regions are interfering with some others and/or are too tiny to be distinguished, it's hard to know the relevant regions for some labels.

For this reason, I thought of categorizing the labels using the same array of colors that was used for the parent layer. In other words, I want each label (i.e. City_id) to be colored with the same color as its referred region.
Had I a small number of regions, I'd do this manually one by one, using the Rule-based method, but this unfortunately isn't the case, as I have several maps, with a total of ~3000 regions.

[image: The regions are categorized by the field: City_id, using random colors]
I guess this is very feasible, if only I could get the code of the categorization that was automatically generated for the layer and apply it the same in the Rule-based labeling.
However, there might probably be much more simple/efficient methods to solve my problem.

Any insight?

[image: I thought of categorizing the labels using Rule-based Labeling]

*Image demonstrating the solution provided by @Mr_Yum below*:

I'm adding the screenshot here, since it can't be added elsewhere (i.e. in a comment):
Having tried the @symbol_color, it worked.
P.S. I had vewed it before, but I didn't think it would work, because I saw in the description (to the right side): current value: #000000 (as seen in the screenshot) and I thought I should use some formula with python to make it work, so I didn't click OK!
[image: Image demonstrating the solution using @symbol_color]
If anyone may add an explanation of how does @symbol_color work, please do to enrich this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable @symbol_color in the buffer color rule.